# How to set the Database Host Name during Oracle enterprise manager installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I'm trying to install Oracle Database for the first time and I'm facing many problem. I, following this [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E73210_01/EMBSC/GUID-D0C8EB92-8297-4FF9-A721-BDD2425243C4.htm#EMBSC162), but I can't understand what should I set in the form shown in section 14. What is the database hostname? How I determine it?

Answer (score 0):

It is described right above the section 14's screenshot:

> The host name must resolve to the local host or virtual host because
>   the host name is used for the local Oracle WebLogic Server as well as
>   the Oracle Management Service. Do not provide a remote host or a load
>   balancer virtual host in this field. Do not enter an IP address. Do
>   not use underscores in the name. Short names are allowed, but you will
>   see a warning, so Oracle recommends that you enter a fully qualified
>   domain name instead.